# Induced automorphism on a blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a surface, $p$ a point on $X$. If $\phi$ is an automorphism on $X$ that fixes $p$ than $\phi$ extends to an automorphism $\tilde \phi$on the blow-up $\widetilde X$ of $X$ in $p$. Then how does $\tilde \phi$ act on the exceptional curve $E_p$? Is it always different from the identity when $\phi \neq id$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action of $\phi$ on the exceptional divisor is induced by the action of the differential at $x$. If this differential is of the form $x\rightarrow cx, c\in C$ it induces the identity on the exceptional divisor.