# Existence of induced automorphism on blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634837/induced-automorphism-on-a-blow-up/1634856#1634856), it was mentioned that an automorphism on a surface $X$ lifts to an automorphism on the blow up $p:\tilde X \to X$ at a point. I have trouble seeing this.

I know about the universal property of blow ups, but it does not seem to be sufficient.
Let $f: X \to X$ an automorphism with inverse $g$, which fixes the point we blow up. By the universal propery of blow-ups, we get morphisms $\bar f: X \to \tilde X$ and $\bar g: X \to \tilde X$
and thus morphisms $\tilde f = \bar f \circ p: \tilde X \to \tilde X$ and $\tilde g = \bar g \circ p: \tilde X \to \tilde X$.

Their composition $\tilde f \circ \tilde g: \tilde X \to \tilde X$ should be the identity, but we don't get this from the above. We only get $p = p \circ \tilde f\circ \tilde g$, so $\tilde f\circ \tilde g$ might swap points on the exceptional divisor.

Comment: In the question you mention, the automorphism fixes the point you are blowing up. Otherwise all bets are off.

Comment: @Mohan: I see. I had this in mind, but forgot to wrote it in the assumptions. I will add it.

Comment: Hint: Look at the differential at the fixed point.